# Dismiss modal and push a segue

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, uistoryboard

I'm pretty new at iOS development and I'm stuck using storyboards. I've a modal view (ZoekCriteriaViewCOntroller) with a button on it. When the button is Pressed I would like to dismiss the view with and push my tableviewcontroller..  I'm getting the error: Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'searchedSegue'.

The segue from ZoekCriteriaViewController to KRoegenTableViewController is called searchedSegue

The code I'm using (C#):

```
                this.DismissViewController(true, () => {
                this.PerformSegue("searchedSegue", this);
            });
```

My storyboard:
[image]

Is anyone able to help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using segues, you don't dismiss the calling controllers! Just do

```
this.PerformSegue("searchedSegue", this);
```